# ServiceStack error with partial files

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack

An error is being thrown on HttpResult.WritePartialTo when writing the file to the response.OutputStream. This is the error I am getting.

> ProtocolViolationException: Bytes to be written to the stream exceed
>   the Content-Length bytes size specified.

Here is the sample code I am using to return the file.

```
/// <summary>
/// The request to get the file for a given media item.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="request"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public HttpResult Get(GetMediaItemFileRequest request)
{
    var mediaItem = _mediaService.GetMediaItemById(request.MediaItemId);

    if (mediaItem == null)
        throw new HttpError(404, "The given mediaitem id could not be located.");

    var file = new FileInfo(mediaItem.GetImagePath());

    var result = new HttpResult(file, GetMimeType(file.FullName));
    result.Headers["MediaItemLength"] = file.Length.ToString(); // this is so that clients don't have to make another request to get the total size (for progress bars)
    result.Headers["MediaExtension"] = file.Extension;
    return result;
}
```

Any ideas why I would be getting this error? I am not doing anything special.

**Update**

It seems that the HttpResultExtensions.AddHttpRangeResponseHeaders is setting the content length to (in my case) 58 bytes. This can't be correct. I am sending more than 58 bytes to the client.

```
public static void AddHttpRangeResponseHeaders(this IHttpResponse response, long rangeStart, long rangeEnd, long contentLength)
{
    response.AddHeader("Content-Range", StringExtensions.Fmt("bytes {0}-{1}/{2}", new object[] { rangeStart, rangeEnd, contentLength }));
    response.StatusCode = 0xce;
    response.SetContentLength((rangeEnd - rangeStart) + 1L);
}
```

Just FYI.

Comment: What is the value of result.Headers["content-length"]?

Comment: 58 bytes. The total file is supposed to be 18 mb so this is must be wrong.

Comment: Try setting that value explicitly to the same value as MediaItemLength

Comment: SetContentLength is set right before the writing to the stream in a compiled library. There is no delegate I can stick anywhere between the two calls.